# Redirect after FB App Request

Tags: jquery, facebook, post, redirect, request

I found some sample code that does fb requests:

But my goal is to redirect after this jquery post? Im not familiar with jquery post....
This code just brings the dialogue box then closes. I want to refresh the page or redirect to another. I am sending the requests to fbrequests which executes some php code that stores request info to my db on my server. I tried putting the redirect there but it doesnt work.

Its

```
   function sendRequest(to) {
FB.ui({method: 'apprequests',
       message: 'data',
       data: to,
       title: 'Invite your Facebook friends.'}, 

       function (response) {
              if (response && response.request_ids) {

                   //since csv, we convert to string
                   var requestIds = "";
                   for(var i = 0; i < response.request_ids.length; i++){
                       requestIds = requestIds + response.request_ids[i] +",";
                    }
                    //modifications
                    //now requestIds is 123,124,125, so we need to remove the last comma after the last id
                    requestIds = requestIds.substring(0,requestIds.length-1);

                    jQuery(function(){
                        jQuery.post("fbrequests", { request_ids: requestIds } );  //jquery post to send csv list of ids to php processing file

                   // window.location.href='http://mysite.com/my-friends'; 
                   });

              } else {

                 //Do something if they don't send it.
                 //alert("Didnt send it");

              }
});
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the wrapping `jQuery(function(){});` and just use:

```
jQuery.post("fbrequests", { request_ids: requestIds }, function(data) {
    // handle the response "data", refresh or redirect here
});
```

Also use the below to join the `request_ids` instead of your code:

```
var requestIds = response.request_ids.join(',');
```

Taken from my tutorial: [How To: Handle Application Requests Using The Facebook Graph API](http://www.masteringapi.com/tutorials/how-to-handle-application-requests-using-the-facebook-graph-api/45/)

Comment: Facebook just recently released Requests 2.0 - LINK - http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/464/ - with this new change request_ids are no longer provided. Instead you get the User Ids this way: var Ids = response.to.join(',');